# how to fill the text in the new form using Selenium+python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

i am trying to automate here and now i want to fill some text in a form which appears after clicking on a button(yellow highlighted one). How to do that??

**Just to be clear, i want to fill the text-field and click the filter . But i am not able to access it . How to do that after i click the funnel button??**

[image]

I tried :

1. i tried to alter the window handle , but it did not work.
2. Directly i accessed the element by css selector, but an error is coming as *'selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable'*

Here is the code :

```
#clicked the button and the form appeared
ddf=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span.k-icon.k-filter').click()
print('Clicked..') #Its working...

#Trying to fill the  text in the form and filter it
#Both the below lines are not working
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input.k-textbox').send_keys('ddf')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.k-button') .click()
print('filtered..')
```

Button html content :
[image]

form html content :
[image]

**UPDATE 1 :**
I got 3 answers, still the prolem persists. **i am able to click the funnel button and filter button, but cant fill the text field in the form **

Comment: Please provide the button's HTML

Comment: @natn2323, i have added the snaps

Comment: Updated the question with text based relevant HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `ActionChains`:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span.k-icon.k-filter').click()

driver.implicitly_wait(2)
input_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input.k-textbox')
filter_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.k-button')

action = ActionChains(driver)
#Update here
action.move_to_element(input_element).click(input_element).send_keys('ddf').perform()
action.move_to_element(filter_element).click(filter_element).perform()
```

Following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
```

**#UPDATE**

Or other approach with `.execute_script`:

```
driver.execute_script('document.querySelector("input.k-textbox").setAttribute("value", "ddf");')
```

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input.k-textbox')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = 'ddf';", element)
```

```
driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('input.k-textbox').innerHTML = 'ddf';");
```

Comment: error is : selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Failed to execute 'elementsFromPoint' on 'Document': The provided double value is non-finite.

Comment: @tedd Please see updated answer, try again and how did it go. I add a `click` method before `send_keys`.

Comment: Still the error is coming. on this line :  action.move_to_element(input_element).click(input_element).send_keys('ddf').perform()

Comment: i am able to click the both funnel shaped and filter button, but not able to wrte the text in the text-filed

Comment: @can you share the url if possible?

Comment: @frianH though the error is disappeared, value 'ddf' is not displaying in the text field.

Comment: sorry for again asking

Comment: @tedd See variant `.execute_script` in last updated.

Answer (score 2):

`ElementNotInteractableException` occurs when an element is found, but you can't be interacted with it because for example element is hidden by another element or is not displayed for some reason and is not clickable anymore.

Does the field for filling filter meet the requirements? Also you didn't say on which exactly step it failed. Anyway maybe using **Wait until an element is visible / clickable** could help in this case. As example:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS, "button.k-button"))
)
```

Comment: The question is how to fill the text field which appears after clicking the yellow highlighted button and click the filter

Comment: i can click the funnel shaped button, but i am not able to fill the rest i.e the text field and filter.

Comment: Which line is the `ElementNotInteractableException` occurring on?

Comment: driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input.k-textbox').send_keys('ddf')

The above line generates the error.
While i am trying to fill the data as DDF in the text field and clicking the filter button..

Comment: As Iwona pointed out, that probably means that `input.k-textbox`, is not visible when the `find_element_by...` line is run.

Comment: @Brydenr ,  i am able to click the both funnel shaped and filter button, but not able to write the text in the text-field

Answer (score 1):

To handle dynamic element Induce `WebDriverWait` and `element_to_be_clickable`()

```
ddf=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"span.k-icon.k-filter")))
ddf.click()
```

You need to import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

If you are getting same error try use `Javascripts Executor` to click.

```
ddf=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"span.k-icon.k-filter")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",ddf)
```

Comment: i can click the funnel shaped button, but i am not able to fill the rest i.e the text field and filter.

Comment: i am able to click the both funnel shaped and filter button, but not able to write the text in the text-filed